# Retrieves the current directory for the current process in winRT

Tags: windows-runtime

Is there any way to find the current directory for the current process in winRT since getCurrentDirectory is not available in winRT ?

Answer (score 2):

Try `Package.Current.InstalledLocation` or `ApplicationData.LocalFolder.InstalledLocation`